# How to distribute the y-ticks proportionally in Chart.js in Flask app?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, chart.js

I am using a Flask app which displays a graph at one point. I'm using Chart.js for displaying the graph. Everything works fine but the y-ticks are not adjusted properly, so my graph ends up looking weird.
because the y-ticks don't start at 0, the "NEGATIVE" bar looks awfully small although it is half of the "POSITIVE" bar.

[image]

I'm passing in values passed from the user into the js code to display the graph. Here is it:

```
  <script>
    // Global parameters:
// do not resize the chart canvas when its container does (keep at 600x400px)
Chart.defaults.global.responsive = false;

// define the chart data
var chartData = {
 labels : [{% for item in labels %}
           "{{item}}",
          {% endfor %}],
 datasets : [{
     label: 'features',
     fill: true,
     lineTension: 0.1,
     backgroundColor: ["#32a852", "#a83232"], 
     borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
     borderCapStyle: 'butt',
     borderDash: [],
     borderDashOffset: 0.0,
     borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
     pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
     pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
     pointBorderWidth: 1,
     pointHoverRadius: 5,
     pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
     pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
     pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
     pointRadius: 1,
     pointHitRadius: 10,
     data : [{% for item in values %}
              {{item}},
            {% endfor %}],
     spanGaps: false
 }]
}

// get chart canvas
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

// create the chart using the chart canvas
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
 type: 'bar',
 data: chartData,
 options: {
  scaleShowValues: true,
  legend: {
    display: false
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        min : 0,
        autoSkip: false
      }
    }]
  }
}
});

options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
}

</script>
```

`values` is a list containing 2 elements corresponding to positive and negative values. How do I make the y-ticks start at 0? Also, the values can really differ, they can be in 100s or even in 1000s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `ticks.min` on the x-axis instead to do it on the y-axis.

Instead of doing this...

```
xAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    min : 0,
    autoSkip: false
  }
}]
```

try this:

```
yAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    min : 0,
    stepSize: 10
  }
}]
```